# To change JBoss 6.1.0 port

Tags: jboss6.x

I'm trying to start JBoss 6.1.0 with 8080 port number. but Oracle RDBMS is running on 8080 port. So i got java.bind error. So i tried to change Jboss AS port to 8181 in \server\all\deploy\jbossweb.sar\server.xml.

But it doesn't make sense. Still i got same error.

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Try changing **bindings-jboss-beans.xml** as below. You can find this file in **${JBOSS_HOME}\server\default\conf\bindingservice.beans\META-INF** folder.

```
<bean class="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
    <property name="serviceName">jboss.web:service=WebServer</property>
    <property name="bindingName">HttpConnector</property>
    <property name="port">8181</property>
    <property name="description">JBoss Web HTTP connector socket; also drives the values for the HTTPS and AJP sockets</property>
</bean>
```

Note:- Make sure in your environmental varibles **JBOSS_HOME** variable points to the correct JBoss folder. 
Note2: This fix is confirmed to work on 6.1.0.Final

Comment: My server on Eclipse did recognize the port change (with "detect from local runtime"), but that didn't really work... Still open only in 8080.

Comment: Editing `deploy\jbossweb.sar\server.xml`(@udi answer) worked for me. Although not recognized automatically by Eclipse.

Answer (score 7):

use parameter jboss.service.binding.set during startup

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01
```

ports-01 increases all ports by 100 i.e. 8180 for http, 8543 for https and so on

ports-02 increases all ports by 200 i.e. 8280 for http, 8643 fir https and so on

so on..

Answer (score 5):

A single change can do the trick
Try this please
go to
**C:\jboss-6.0.0.20100429-M3\server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar\server.xml**

find the following lines

> -- A HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 
>          Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" **port="${jboss.web.http.port}"**  address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
>                  connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="${jboss.web.https.port}"

change into

> -- A HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 
>          Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="**portnumber**" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
>                  connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="${jboss.web.https.port}"

portnumber in the sense any value as your wish.For example 8081,8082,8083,,,,,, go on.

Hope this will help

Answer (score 2):

For JBoss 6.1, you can change the port number from file `standalone.xml` in `\JBOSS_HOME\jboss-eap-6.1\standalone\configuration`:

```
<socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this procedure to avoid java.bind error.

If you`re running on`Linux`, try this command at the start

```
./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000
```

If you`re working on`Windows` environment,

```
standalone.bat -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000
```

By providing value `1000` for `jboss.socket.binding.port-offset`, you add **"1000"** to all `portbindings` on the server, very **useful for running multiple instances** of `JBoss` on the same machine , **to avoid port conflicts**.